# Evaluating $\int\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluating $$\int\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}\mathrm dx$$

I had read the [similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887784/evaluating-int-x-sqrt-frac1-x21x2-dx), but it doesn't work.

Comment: No matter what you do, this is not going to be a pretty integral.

Comment: Do a trigonometric substitution.

Comment: $1 + tan^{2}{\theta} = sec^{2}{\theta}$

Comment: $1 - sin^{2}{\theta} = cos^{2}{\theta}$

Comment: It seems that this is non-elementary, Mathematica replies $-i E(i\,\text{arsinh}\,(x),-1)$, where $E$ is some elliptic function.

Comment: Byrd, P. F. and Friedman, M. D., Handbook Of Elliptic Integrals For Engineers And Physicists, page 50. There is a section devoted to integrals involving $\sqrt{a^2-t^2}$ and $\sqrt{b^2+t^2}$. 214.03 is what you are looking for. The substitution that's being used is : $$ \sin^2u = \frac{t^2(a^2+b^2)}{a^2(b^2+t^2)}$$

Comment: @Ali I had tried by your way. We obtain $\sin^2u=\dfrac{2x^2}{1+x^2},\quad \cos^2u=\dfrac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$. But when we calculus the differentiation, it follows the complexity.

Comment: @DDK: I honesty didn't try the substitution myself. I'll be glad to copy the corresponding pages from the book for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I had read the similar problem, but it doesn't work*.

Of [course](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) it [doesn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) ! The integral you posted is nothing else than the formula for the [arc length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length)

of the $($co$)$sine function, which is rather famous for giving rise [historically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler) to the study of [elliptic 

 integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) ! In particular, $\displaystyle\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\sqrt{1+\sin^2x}~dx~=~\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\sqrt{1+\cos^2x}~dx~=~\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{1~{\color{red}+}~x^2}{1~{\color{red}-}~x^2}}~dx$

$=~\dfrac{\Gamma^2\bigg(\dfrac14\bigg)}{4\sqrt{2\pi}}~{\color{red}+}~\dfrac{\pi\sqrt{2\pi}}{\Gamma^2\bigg(\dfrac14\bigg)}$ . Of course, you will immediately object that this is not the integral you 
 posted; but this is only half-true, since we have $\displaystyle\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{1~{\color{red}-}~x^2}{1~{\color{red}+}~x^2}}~dx~=~\dfrac{\Gamma^2\bigg(\dfrac14\bigg)}{4\sqrt{2\pi}}~{\color{red}-}~\dfrac{\pi\sqrt{2\pi}}{\Gamma^2\bigg(\dfrac14\bigg)}$ .

The reason for this lies in the fact that, in general, $\displaystyle\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{1+x^n}{1-x^n}}~dx~=~a\cdot2^{a-1}~\bigg[\frac12~B\bigg(\frac a2,\frac a2\bigg)$

${\color{red}+}~B\bigg(\dfrac{a+1}2,\dfrac {a+1}2\bigg)\bigg]$, where $a={\color{red}+}~\dfrac1n$ , and $\displaystyle\int_0^1\sqrt[n]{\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}}~dx~=~a\cdot2^{a-1}~\bigg[\frac12~B\bigg(\frac a2,\frac a2\bigg)~{\color{red}-}$

${\color{red}-}~B\bigg(\dfrac{a+1}2,\dfrac {a+1}2\bigg)\bigg]$, where $a={\color{red}-}~\dfrac1n$ . See the [beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and [$\Gamma$ functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) for more information.