# Sine wavelength in terms of arc length and amplitude

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, arc-length

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the wavelength of a sine function from a specified arc length and peak-to-peak amplitude.

I'm using this formula to generate a sine wave mould for a mechanical press, which needs to line up with other parts.  Think of a sheet of graph paper being bent into the shape of a sine wave.  How would I ensure the lines on the paper match up with the peaks and valleys of the sine wave?

I started with the basic formula for a sine wave:
$$y=\frac A2 \sin \left( \frac {2\pi x}{\lambda} \right) $$

Then took the derivative:
$$\frac {d}{dx} = \frac {\pi A \cos \left( \frac {2\pi x}{\lambda} \right) }{\lambda}$$

I applied this to the standard arc length formula:
$$\int_0^\lambda \sqrt {1+ \left( \frac{d}{dx} \right) ^2} dx$$

$$\int_0^\lambda \sqrt {1+ \left( \frac{\pi A \cos \left( \frac{2 \pi X}{\lambda} \right) } {\lambda} \right) ^2} dx$$

Trying to solve this integral leads to things like elliptic integrals.  Unfortunately, this is where my math skills end.  How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Why is your integral from o to $\lambda$? Assume $x_1$ and $x_2$, have the integral for this range to get the length. You have two other equations for the amplitudes. I wonder if there is a unique solution.

Comment: I chose $0$ to $\theta$ because I'm interested in the arc length of a single period.  I'm not sure what you mean by $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: There's no way to avoid elliptic functions here, but http://tinyurl.com/hcldrcf may help

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410439) question.