# How to calculate $\int_{0}^1 \sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}dx$?

Tags: definite-integrals

I encounter the following question:
 $$\int_{0}^1 \sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}dx=?$$
It looks simple. But I doubt there exists analytic solution. Could anyone help? Thank you!

---

Icarus 369 has  pointed out Page [ [Evaluating $\int\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}\mathrm dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410439/evaluating-int-sqrt-frac1-x21x2-mathrm-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1) ].
The question indeed has no elementary solution.

Thanks Icarus 369.

---

The elliptic integration turns out to be very interesting. FYI: http://web.mst.edu/~lmhall/SPFNS/sfch3.pdf

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki, have tried, but get a mess of formulae, which can not be calculated.

Comment: Have you tried the change of variable : $x=sin(\theta)$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie $dx=\cos(\theta) d\theta$ becomes a trouble term

Comment: The indefinite integral can't be solved using elementary functions.(the solution involves eliptic integral).

Comment: Numerical Integration $\simeq0.7$

Comment: The change of variable I indicated has the merit to make the radical disappear... a classical objective in most algebraic computations when it is possible.

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki@lcarus 369, Thanks. I try to check whether 0.7.. is some combination of pi and rationals to get some hints. But sadly, failed ....

Comment: @JeanMarie ??....

Comment: I beg your pardon. The radical doesn't disappear.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410439/evaluating-int-sqrt-frac1-x21x2-mathrm-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Icarus 369, Thanks!

Comment: This has no closed form. Wolfram gives the answer as $2K(-1)-E(-1)$ where $K(n)$ is the [Complete Elliptic Integral of the First Kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html) and $E(n)$ is the [Elliptic Integral of the Second Kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html).

Comment: you can probably use $u=sin(2x)$ also.